# Print list elements in email body - 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I am making a script which checks a website for auctions interested for me. If it finds an interested link, it adds this link to `listalink` with `listalink.append(link)`. When I am sending an email I have this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

# listalink example:
listalink = ["http://www.google.pl", "http://www.facebook.com", "http://amazon.com"]

def email_sender():
   fromaddr = "test_e_mail@wp.pl"
   toaddr = "myemail@gmail.com"
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = fromaddr
   msg['To'] = toaddr
   msg['Subject'] = "NEW INTERESTED AUCTIONS"
   body = listalink
   msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
   server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.wp.pl", 465)
   server_ssl.ehlo()
   server_ssl.login("test_e_mail@wp.pl", "password")
   text = msg.as_string()
   server_ssl.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
   server_ssl.close()
   print 'E-mail sent'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error occurs because you add `list` to email's body (the body must be `str`):

```
body = listalink
```

Solution:

```
listalink = ["http://www.google.pl", "http://www.facebook.com", "http://amazon.com"]
listalink = " ".join(listalink)
```